# How to set an icon of Microsoft Teams Card in a chat?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I followed [this Microsoft's tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for sending a chat message via MS Graph api.

But I am unable to set the icon in the top left corner (see attached picture)

[image]

How to edit that icon?

*** EDIT ***
Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use the teamsAppId field indication to show the additional app Icon. Could you please check if this helps - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-9-send-message-that-contains-cards-that-are-attributed-to-a-teams-app

Comment: I tried to add teamsAppId into the request but I got Error 403 with message "Application with AAD App Id '977c913c-4206-49cd-a8f2-1b542e4345ad' is not authorized to include Teams App Id '977c913c-4206-49cd-a8f2-1b542e4345ad' in the payload."

Comment: Could you please confirm if the points mentioned in the Note here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-8 are followed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

The "teamsAppId" is identifier from MS TEAMS not from the Azure portal App registration.

For example: https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/policies/manage-apps/**e370c1f7-e088-4db4-94ce-f43e62ad78a7**

I was trying to somehow insert clientId from Azure portal...

I was confused because this ID ("teamsAppId") is not present in my manifest nor in my bot source code.

Answer (score 0):

This image is set by setting the Bot *Icon* property in the Azure portal - see image below:

[image]

Be aware per the note, it can take a little while to update.