# Application with AAD App Id {APP_ID} is not authorized to include Teams App Id {APP_ID} in the payload

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, access-token

I spent many hours on how to get this working...

I need to send a Hero card from API server to MS Teams chat via MS Graph. I need the card to have the same icon as my installed application.

From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-9-send-message-that-contains-cards-that-are-attributed-to-a-teams-app) example I found out that teamsAppId is required. But after I added API permissions to the app and granted access and got Access token on behalf a user I am still getting en **error 403 Forbidden** saying:

```
Application with AAD App Id '977c913c-4206-49cd-a8f2-1b542e4345ad' is not authorized to include Teams App Id '977c913c-4206-49cd-a8f2-1b542e4345ad' in the payload.
```

This is my POST request URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/19:9cb8615d-f553-42a2-8801-7308dd10b841_e87a7081-0945-4640-9950-bef1cea65b13@unq.gbl.spaces/messages
```

And this is my entire request body:

```
{
"subject": null,
"body": {
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "<attachment id=\"malickypavoucek\"></attachment>"
},
"attachments": [
    {
        "id": "malickypavoucek",
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
        "contentUrl": null,
        "content": "{  \"title\": \"Device: Ultrasound scan\",  \"text\": \"Access granted. (Id: 5)\",  \"buttons\": [    {      \"type\": \"openUrl\",      \"title\": \"Open session (browser link)\",      \"value\": \"https://test.com\"    },    {      \"type\": \"openUrl\",      \"title\": \"Open session (app link)\",      \"value\": \"https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/apps/e370c1f7-e088-4db4-94ce-f43e62ad78a7/sections/index0\"    }  ]}",
        "name": null,
        "thumbnailUrl": null,
        "teamsAppId": "977c913c-4206-49cd-a8f2-1b542e4345ad"

    }
]
```

}

These are the scopes I am requesting in an access token request:

```
offline_access user.read chat.read chat.ReadWrite TeamsActivity.Send TeamsActivity.Read ChannelMessage.ReadWrite
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's possible you're mixing up the *Azure* App Id with the *Teams Manifest* App Id - they're not the same at all.

Comment: Please see my second question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75672772/how-to-set-an-icon-of-microsoft-teams-card-in-a-chat addressing the same problem. I added a screenshots that show the IDs.

Comment: I see the *Azure* App Id is "977c913c...", but what is the Teams App Id - that's a DIFFERENT guid file, found in the Teams manifest file (the json file, usually near the top).

Comment: I found a solution!

The "teamsAppId" is identifier from MS TEAMS not from the Azure portal App registration.

For example: https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/policies/manage-apps/e370c1f7-e088-4db4-94ce-f43e62ad78a7

I was trying to somehow insert clientId from Azure portal...

I was confused because this ID ("teamsAppId") is not present in my manifest nor in my bot source code.

Comment: That's what I was saying, it's NOT your "Azure" App Id, but this was still a surprise for me, good to know what you found. This Id you're referring to is actually not found in any files - I think it's kind of like the "instance" of your app within that specific tenant - if that's correct, be aware that it will change then from tenant to tenant, you'd need to do a lookup first before using it, via Graph.